# Object is possibly 'undefined' in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

So here's my component: I'm making a GET request from a mockAPI, which is this structure:

```
"usuarios": [
    {
      "nome": "foo bar",
      "cpf": "213.123.123-45",
      "email": "foo_bar@email.com",
      "endereco": {
        "cep": 13454000,
        "rua": "rua talvez",
        "numero": 785,
        "bairro": "bairro azul",
        "cidade": "cidade eterna"
      },
      "id": 1
    },
```

and so on.

When I log the response.data it works fine and also when I log the state it works just fine, but when I try to log the objects inside the array of the userList state, i get the 'Object is possibly undefined'.

```
const UserList: React.FC = () => {
  const endpoint = "http://localhost:5000/usuarios";
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState();

  const getApi = () => {
    axios
      .get(endpoint)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setUserList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getApi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(userList[0])}>SEE THE API</button>
```

[...]

I've looked around and saw some people saying that I should change how strict the ts.config would be for these things but I was advised not to. I can't seem to access the values of the objects inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you declared:

```
const [userList, setUserList] = useState();
```

The default value of `userList` is `undefined`. Thus accessing `userList[0]` would potentially raise runtime error.

Two ways to fix it:

1. `const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);` default to empty array.
2. `onClick={() => console.log(userList?.[0])}` optional chaining operator to prevent runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing the data incorrectly. As per your api response data structure, you need to access using `userList.usuarios[0]` and not `userList[0]`

```js
return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(userList.usuarios[0])}>SEE THE API</button>
```

Alternatively you can set the state like this:

```js
.then((response) => {
   setUserList(response.data.usuarios);
  ...
```

and finally, make sure to add default value to your state.

```js
const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. In the intermediate state before the request completes, the `userList` will indeed be `undefined`. TypeScript is forcing you to handle this case.

One solution is to add a loading indicator:

```
if (!userList) return <p>Loading...</p>;
```

Alternatively, add an empty but valid initial state:

```
const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
```